# Pydantic type-safe field reference in exclude

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I have the following code:

```
class MyBaseClass(BaseModel, metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    string_field: str
    int_field: int

    def as_dict(self) -> dict[str, Any]:
        return self.dict(exclude=["int_field"])


class MySpecificClass(MyBaseClass):
    int_field = 123
    bool_field: bool


> MySpecificClass(...).as_dict()
```

I aim to serialize `MySpecificClass` (and other inheriting classes) and I don't want `int_field` in the result dict.
The current approach works fine, however, I don't like passing field names as strings since it may be error-prone (during renaming, deletion, etc.) and IDE is not referencing it correctly.

Is there any way to reference the field in a type-safe way, where IDE and application will complain after `int_field` is deleted?
Note: Writing custom code that will check that on startup is not an option here

The `Field` and `Config` approaches are not working correctly, since they're not inherited.

```
int_field: int = Field(int, exclude=True)

class Config:
    exclude = {"int_field"}
```

I'm using pydantic `1.10.12` and can't upgrade it now.